# Why can't a nonabelian group of order $8$ have exactly four elements of order $4$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a nonabelian group of order $8$. Necessarily$^\dagger$, $|Z(G)|=2$. Accordingly$^{\dagger\dagger}$, every noncentral elements of $G$ must have centralizer of order $4$. Therefore (orbit-stabilizer), $G$ splits into two central singleton classes, say $\mathcal C_1=\{e\}$ and $\mathcal C_2=\{x\}$, and three noncentral doublet classes, say $\mathcal D_1=\{y_1,y_2\}$, $\mathcal D_2=\{y_3,y_4\}$, $\mathcal D_3=\{y_5,y_6\}$. Since $x$ commutes with every element of $G$, then $x^k$ will do, for every integer $k$, and hence $\langle x\rangle \le Z(G)$, namely $o(x)=2$. The elements in the same conjugacy class have the same order, and at least one amongst the $\mathcal D_i$'s [has its elements of order $4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1451374/1092170), say wlog $\mathcal D_1$. So, in principle we might have both $\mathcal D_2$ and $\mathcal D_3$ made of elements of order $2$ or of order $4$, but also one-and-one. I'm looking for an argument by contradiction ruling out this latter option, as I know that the only nonabelian groups of order $8$ are $D_4$ (with two elements of order $4$) and $Q_8$ (with six elements of order $4$). Some other fact that could possibly be relevant here are:

- in general, automorphisms of a group send conjugacy classes to conjugacy classes, while preserving elements' order and classes' sizes;
- for $G$ a nonabelian group of order $8$, we get $\operatorname{Inn}(G)\cong C_2^2$ (by the "cyclic $G/Z(G)$ argument");
- there are $1\pmod 2$ subgroups of order $4$, but this is still compatible with two cylic subgroups of order $4$ (and hence four elements of order $4$) and a third subgroup of order $4$ isomorphic to Klein's 4-group (which would account for the three elements of order $2$).

So, how to rule out that $G$ has exactly four elements of order $4$ (or, equivalently, exactly three elements of order $2$)?

---

$^\dagger$In fact, $|Z(G)|=4$ is ruled out, as otherwise $G/Z(G)$ would be cyclic. And $|Z(G)|=1$ is ruled out by the class equation and the fact that there aren't conjugacy classes of sizes $3$ or $7$.

$^{\dagger\dagger}$For $x\in G\setminus Z(G)$, strictly: $Z(G)<C_G(x)<G$. Then apply Lagrange's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $|G| = 8$, and suppose that $G$ has at least $4$ elements of order $4$.

Then we can find two different cyclic subgroups of order $4$. (A cyclic subgroup of order $4$ has two elements of order $4$, a generator and its inverse.)

Let $H = \langle x \rangle$ be a cyclic subgroup of order $4$, and let $K = \langle y \rangle$ be another one.

Steps:

- $H$ and $K$ are of index $2$, so they are normal in $G$.
- $G = HK$ and $H \cap K$ has order $2$, so $H \cap K = \langle x^2 \rangle = \langle y^2 \rangle$.
- Because $G = HK$ is nonabelian, we have $xy \neq yx$. Therefore $y^{-1}xy \neq x$.
- On the other hand by normality $y^{-1}xy \in H$, and $y^{-1}xy$ has order $4$, so $y^{-1}xy = x^{-1}$.
- Then $(xy)^2 = y^2$. (Multiply both sides of $y^{-1}xy = x^{-1}$ by $xy$ to get $y^{-1}(xy)^2 = y$.)

So we can conclude that $xy$ is also an element of order $4$. And since $xy \not\in H$ and $xy \not\in K$, we have more than $4$ elements of order $4$ in $G$.

Actually, at this point it is pretty easy to see that $$G = \{1,z,x,x^{-1},y,y^{-1},xy,(xy)^{-1} \}$$ where $z \in Z(G)$ with $z = x^2 = y^2 = (xy)^2$. Then you are not too far from showing that $G$ must be isomorphic to the quaternion group $Q_8$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $y_i$ has order $4$. Then the centralizer of $y_i$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and contains $x$ as an element of order $2$ and $y_i$ as element of order $4$: then $y_i^2=x$.

The case that you want to rule out is $y_i^2=x$ for $i \leq 4$, and $y_5^2=y_6^2=e$. So assume we’re in this case.

Note that $y_5x$ has order $2$ (dividing $2$ and not $1$) and is distinct from $x,y_5$, hence $y_6=y_5x$.

The subgroup generated by $y_1$ has cardinality $4$, hence index $2$, so that $y_2=y_1^{-1}=y_1x$.

Now, $y_5$ is not contained in the centralizer of $y_1$, so $y_5y_1y_5^{-1}=y_1^{-1}$, hence $(y_5y_1)^2=e$. But $y_5y_1$ is neither $e$, nor $x=y_1^2$, nor $y_5$, nor $y_6=y_5x$. Hence the contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Say that $\mathcal{D}_2$ and $\mathcal{D}_3$ both consist of elements of order $4$.

Let $H=\langle y_3\rangle$, $K=\langle y_5\rangle$. They are both normal, and by size considerations their intersection is of order $2$ and $G=HK$. In addition, the centralizer of $y_3$ has order $4$, hence is equal to $H$; since it also contains $x$, then $y_3^2=x$, and likewise $y_5^2=x$. Note that $y_5$ does not centralize $y_3$, so $y_5y_3y_5^{-1}=y_3^{-1}$.

Now, $y_1\in HK$; so $y_1 = y_3^ay_5^b$ for some $a,b$. Neither can be even (as then $y_1$ would lie in $H$ or in $K$). Replacing $y_3$ with $y_3^{-1}$ we may assume $a=1$.
If $b=1$, then
$$y_1^2 = y_3y_5y_3y_5 = y_3(y_5y_3y_5^{-1})y_5^2 = y_3y_3^{-1}y_5^3 = y_5^2\neq x,$$
so $y_1$ is not of order $2$. If $b=3$, then
$$y_1^2 = y_3y_5^3y_3y_5^3 = y_3y_5^{-1}y_3y_5^{-1} = y_3(y_5^{-1}y_3y_5)(y_5^{-2})=y_3y_3^{-1}y_5^2 = y_5^2\neq e,$$
so again $y_1$ is not of order $2$.

Thus, $y_1$ is also of order $4$.